# how to remove extra button in tkinter hierarchy treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKHx7.png)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2CHY.png)

the Treeview has a button on the top of buttons of the tree
refer the screen shot above !

Comment: It is not clear what *button* you refer.  Is it the *minus* sign?  Or the dotted border around the text?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @acw1668 the top most button which comes by default

Comment: Set `show='tree'` when creating the treeview.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks a lot ! it worked !